How to convert netcdf time series data into individual text data which is classified based on latitude?
I am preparing new input data for a fortran-based DGVM, but I am having trouble adjusting the data according to the DGVM format that will be used. I'm doing this task on a linux server.
Here is the climate data that I will use:
download climate data
MIROC6 historical monthly air temperature data from 1851 to 1860 (0.5 x 0.5).
I need to these steps in order

The text output data must be separated into 360 folders (each folder represent latitudes from 1-360)
sample folders 1-360
In each folder there will be 720 text files (which represent longitude 1-720 on that latitude/folder)
sample txt files inside each folder: 1-720
Inside the txt file, the order of the data from top to bottom represents monthly data (January to December, and repeated).

I tried converting the netcdf data by several method: CDO, NCO and ncdump comamnd and I'm able to get in one .txt format for whole grid value. But it will take huge time to extract/ classify the individual grid value according to the needed format manually.
I hope there is other efficient way to convert those data, and I hope there is someone who willing to help me with this matter.
Thank you.

Welcome to SO. Please try to make questions self-contained. I'm pretty sure no one reading this question has any idea what DGVM is, so will struggle to follow the Q. Also, if you have tried things, show us. Maybe what you've tried is already very efficient. However, based on the question, you should look at the distrgrid operator in CDO, which might solve your problem https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo.pdf#page=48.06.

If you know python you can pretty easily do this with xarray. However, writing small amount of data to so many individual text files seems kind of inefficient, couldn't you just read the NetCDF file from fortran directly?

@RobertWilson I'm sorry, I didn't explain more about DGVM. Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried using cdo distgrid, but using cdo outputtab is more efficient.
I have created a simple bash script, for the extraction process.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mxZQrWAnqUPuD0VrUDom2LCU9nvJu7sS/view?usp=sharing
I want to cast the script program on another queue (with the name: ib.q@node02, using 20 CPUs), but until now I still get an error. As default, any jobs will run under general queue
Could you please help me how to run the bash script on a specific (different) queue?
Thank you.

@kakk11 Okay, I will consider using python xarray if it can run faster. Yes you are right, but this is the default model setting that I need to use, there will be quite a big change if I change this structure. maybe it will be considered next time. Thanks for the suggestion.
I have created a simple bash script to extract netcdf into individual txt. I explained it in the previous comment
I want to run the bash script (.sh), on a specific queue using a specific CPU, to speed up the process. Do you have any suggestions for this?
Thank you.

Remember, SO is not a coding service. If you have a new question post it, do not expect people to answer in the comments

@RobertWilson Apologize for this mistake, I'll do it. Thank you

I found a solution by using the CDO outputtab operator in a loop, written in a simple Linux bash script. The conversion process is done every 20 points to avoid putting a heavy load on the server's CPU (this can be adjusted).
The code I created is as follows:
#!/bin/bash

# Define input file and log file
input_file="/path/canesm5_r1i1p1f1_w5e5_ssp126_tas_global_daily_2015_2100_05gc.nc"
log_file="log.txt"

# Remove existing log file if it exists
rm -f $log_file

# Function to extract data for a specific latitude
extract_latitude() {
    lat=$1
    lon_index=1
    max_jobs=20
    job_count=0

    # Loop through longitudes from -180 to 180 in 0.5 degree increments
    for lon in $(seq -180 0.5 179.5); do
        # Define the output file name based on the current latitude and longitude index
        output_file="${lat}_${lon_index}.txt"
        
        # Extract data for the grid point at the current latitude and longitude, save only values, and remove the header
        (cdo -outputtab,value -remapnn,lon=${lon}_lat=${lat} $input_file | sed '1d' > $output_file) &>> $log_file &
        
        # Increment the longitude index and job count
        lon_index=$((lon_index + 1))
        job_count=$((job_count + 1))

        # Check if the max number of jobs has been reached
        if [ $job_count -ge $max_jobs ]; then
            wait  # Wait for all background jobs to complete
            job_count=0  # Reset job count
        fi
    done

    # Wait for any remaining background processes to finish
    wait
}

# Loop through latitudes from 90N to -90S in 0.5 degree increments
for lat in $(seq 90 -0.5 -90); do
    echo "Extracting data for latitude $lat"
    extract_latitude $lat
done

echo "Data extraction completed. Check $log_file for details."


Thank you
